# Add custom user field for each product in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have just started to use django for web development and couldn't figure something out,

I want to be able to define different required fields for my e-commerce django website and those input fields show up in the product page.
Then users fill those input fields when adding them to them to their cart. For example in a t-shirt product page be able  to define 'color' , 'size' and 'custom print'

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py

```
class yourmodel(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(blank=False,null=False,primary_key=True)
    yourfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=False)
    yourfield2 = models.TextField(null=True,blank=False)
```

With blank=false when the user tries to insert the form if he has not filled in the input field, django stops him and does not accept the insertion of the row